# The WSO2 APIM access token cannot request scope with roles defined

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have configured wso2am-3.1.0 with wso2is-km-5.10.0 using the following guide.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#step-1-download-prepackaged-wso2-is-as-a-key-manager-wso2-is-km

Both of them are using the same LDAP as the secondary user store and I can authenticate both of them using the LDAP user without problem.

I have assigned "**Internal/subscriber**" role to user called "**normal**" and published an API with scope "**am_subscribe**" which requires role "**Internal/subscriber**".

However, when I try to request the access from APIM using the method provided in the guide below with "scope=am_subscribe", it always returns the access token with "**default**" scope only.

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/a-6-step-guide-for-jwt-exchange-with-oauth2

```
{
  "access_token": "x",
  "refresh_token": "x",
  "scope": "default",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Is there something missing in order to request the scope?

Comment: Are you sure the app is subscribed to the API? Can you invoke the other non-scoped resources of the same API with this token?

Comment: Yes, the app is subscribed to the API. I can invoke non-scoped resources of the same API with this token.

Comment: If I set the "scope=openid am_subscribe", I can get the idToken but the return scope will be "openid" only without "am_subscribe".